# How do i change a variable of another class?

Tags: java, android, static, protected, non-static

I have a variable in the class "MainActivity" with the name modeNr, it is protected so it should be accessible from within the package, however whenever I try to alter it from a class in the same package it gives the error: "Non-static field 'modeNr' cannot be referenced from a static context". I use the following line to alter the variable:

MainActivity.modeNr = 1;

Any ideas on what the problem is and how to correct it?

Comment: Yes, instantiate MainActivity.

Comment: The answers in comments and those below will help achieve what you want. But the approach is totally impractical. What are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there is a better way to do whatever it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to change non-static member from static function. you need to make that varible static as well or need to create object of that class.
lets suppose,

```
class Test {
 int node = 0;
 static int node1 =10; 

}

class changeNode {

public static void changeNode(){
 new Test().node = somevalue;
//or you need to make node static and change like this
Test.node1 = some value 

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment.

Your modeNr is not static variable. You need to define it like:

```
protected static String modeNr="ddddd"
```

since you modify it by MainActivity.modeNr, in this way the variable must be a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of that error you need to define your variable as static.

```
static String modeNr="soemthing"
```

To access a static variable either access it via static member or via an object.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `modeNr` variable `static`.

And I think the log `Non-static field 'modeNr' cannot be referenced from a static context` is explaining everything.